# Dynamic SVG battery icon

Tags: html, css, xml, svg

How I can make the green group have size in percentage?

In this case, It's size is equivalent to his max 100%. How I made it size dinamically with percent?

http://codepen.io/daniellmesquita/pen/mPGbyr

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="338pt" height="168pt" viewBox="0 0 338 168" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="#000000ff">
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 10.50 0.00 L 73.50 0.00 C 73.51 6.99 73.48 13.97 73.52 20.96 C 56.02 21.05 38.51 20.97 21.01 21.00 C 20.94 40.85 21.11 60.70 20.92 80.54 C 13.95 80.46 6.97 80.52 0.00 80.50 L 0.00 17.49 C 3.50 17.51 6.99 17.50 10.49 17.49 C 10.52 11.66 10.49 5.83 10.50 0.00 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 94.50 0.00 L 157.50 0.00 C 157.51 6.98 157.47 13.95 157.54 20.93 C 136.52 21.06 115.49 21.02 94.47 20.95 C 94.52 13.97 94.49 6.98 94.50 0.00 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 178.50 0.00 L 241.50 0.00 C 241.54 6.95 241.41 13.91 241.59 20.86 C 220.56 21.16 199.51 20.96 178.48 20.96 C 178.52 13.97 178.49 6.99 178.50 0.00 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 262.50 0.00 L 287.00 0.00 C 287.00 16.00 286.99 32.00 287.00 48.00 C 304.00 48.01 321.00 48.00 338.00 48.00 L 338.00 119.00 C 321.00 119.00 304.00 118.99 287.00 119.01 C 286.89 127.21 287.21 135.41 286.84 143.61 C 279.91 143.38 272.97 143.54 266.03 143.52 C 265.94 123.67 266.05 103.82 265.97 83.98 C 265.94 81.27 267.36 78.76 267.04 76.02 C 266.71 69.70 267.76 63.26 266.02 57.09 C 265.97 45.08 266.02 33.07 266.00 21.07 C 264.81 21.01 263.62 20.94 262.44 20.85 C 262.57 13.90 262.47 6.95 262.50 0.00 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 0.00 101.50 C 6.99 101.50 13.98 101.51 20.97 101.49 C 21.07 120.12 20.92 138.76 21.05 157.39 C 19.87 157.45 18.69 157.51 17.51 157.57 C 17.50 161.04 17.49 164.52 17.50 168.00 L 0.00 168.00 L 0.00 101.50 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 38.48 147.03 C 59.49 146.97 80.50 146.99 101.51 147.02 C 101.49 154.01 101.50 161.01 101.50 168.00 L 38.50 168.00 C 38.50 161.01 38.51 154.02 38.48 147.03 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 122.45 147.10 C 143.47 146.91 164.50 146.99 185.53 147.05 C 185.47 154.04 185.51 161.02 185.50 168.00 L 122.50 168.00 C 122.48 161.03 122.55 154.06 122.45 147.10 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 206.48 147.04 C 227.49 146.97 248.50 146.98 269.52 147.03 C 269.48 154.02 269.51 161.01 269.50 168.00 L 206.50 168.00 C 206.49 161.01 206.52 154.03 206.48 147.04 Z" />
</g>
<g id="#1f6e43ff">
<path fill="#1f6e43" opacity="1.00" d=" M 37.00 37.00 C 108.33 37.00 179.67 37.00 251.00 37.00 C 251.00 68.67 251.00 100.33 251.00 132.00 C 179.67 132.00 108.33 132.00 37.00 132.00 C 37.00 100.33 37.00 68.67 37.00 37.00 Z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The question here is not the dynamic resizing.

Comment: Daniell Mesquita – yes; my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what (I think) you want by turning the green "power level" group into a child `<svg>` element.  You can set the child `<svg>` to have a position and size equivalent to the original green rectangle, then add a child rectangle to that which uses percentages for its dimensions.  That rect will become your "power level".

```
<svg id="#1f6e43ff" x="37" y="37" width="214" height="95" >
  <rect width="75%" height="100%" fill="#1f6e43"/>
</svg>
```

That means we can set the battery power level by giving the `width` attribute of the rectangle any percentage value you like.  For example, here I have set it to 75%.

Full demo below:

```html
<svg width="338pt" height="168pt" viewBox="0 0 338 168" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="#000000ff">
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 10.50 0.00 L 73.50 0.00 C 73.51 6.99 73.48 13.97 73.52 20.96 C 56.02 21.05 38.51 20.97 21.01 21.00 C 20.94 40.85 21.11 60.70 20.92 80.54 C 13.95 80.46 6.97 80.52 0.00 80.50 L 0.00 17.49 C 3.50 17.51 6.99 17.50 10.49 17.49 C 10.52 11.66 10.49 5.83 10.50 0.00 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 94.50 0.00 L 157.50 0.00 C 157.51 6.98 157.47 13.95 157.54 20.93 C 136.52 21.06 115.49 21.02 94.47 20.95 C 94.52 13.97 94.49 6.98 94.50 0.00 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 178.50 0.00 L 241.50 0.00 C 241.54 6.95 241.41 13.91 241.59 20.86 C 220.56 21.16 199.51 20.96 178.48 20.96 C 178.52 13.97 178.49 6.99 178.50 0.00 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 262.50 0.00 L 287.00 0.00 C 287.00 16.00 286.99 32.00 287.00 48.00 C 304.00 48.01 321.00 48.00 338.00 48.00 L 338.00 119.00 C 321.00 119.00 304.00 118.99 287.00 119.01 C 286.89 127.21 287.21 135.41 286.84 143.61 C 279.91 143.38 272.97 143.54 266.03 143.52 C 265.94 123.67 266.05 103.82 265.97 83.98 C 265.94 81.27 267.36 78.76 267.04 76.02 C 266.71 69.70 267.76 63.26 266.02 57.09 C 265.97 45.08 266.02 33.07 266.00 21.07 C 264.81 21.01 263.62 20.94 262.44 20.85 C 262.57 13.90 262.47 6.95 262.50 0.00 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 0.00 101.50 C 6.99 101.50 13.98 101.51 20.97 101.49 C 21.07 120.12 20.92 138.76 21.05 157.39 C 19.87 157.45 18.69 157.51 17.51 157.57 C 17.50 161.04 17.49 164.52 17.50 168.00 L 0.00 168.00 L 0.00 101.50 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 38.48 147.03 C 59.49 146.97 80.50 146.99 101.51 147.02 C 101.49 154.01 101.50 161.01 101.50 168.00 L 38.50 168.00 C 38.50 161.01 38.51 154.02 38.48 147.03 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 122.45 147.10 C 143.47 146.91 164.50 146.99 185.53 147.05 C 185.47 154.04 185.51 161.02 185.50 168.00 L 122.50 168.00 C 122.48 161.03 122.55 154.06 122.45 147.10 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 206.48 147.04 C 227.49 146.97 248.50 146.98 269.52 147.03 C 269.48 154.02 269.51 161.01 269.50 168.00 L 206.50 168.00 C 206.49 161.01 206.52 154.03 206.48 147.04 Z" />
</g>
<svg id="1f6e43ff" x="37" y="37" width="214" height="95" >
  <rect width="75%" height="100%" fill="#1f6e43"/>
</svg>
</svg>
```

The above demonstrates how you can set the level with percentages in a static file. But I suspect you really wanted to know how to change the level with Javascript.

It's pretty easy.  We just need to give the green rectangle an `id` attribute (eg. `id="level"`), get a reference to the element using `getElementById()`, then set its width attribute to the value we want.

```
document.getElementById("level").setAttribute("width", "25%");
```

Demo below:

```js
document.getElementById("level").setAttribute("width", "25%");
```

```html
<svg width="338pt" height="168pt" viewBox="0 0 338 168" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="#000000ff">
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 10.50 0.00 L 73.50 0.00 C 73.51 6.99 73.48 13.97 73.52 20.96 C 56.02 21.05 38.51 20.97 21.01 21.00 C 20.94 40.85 21.11 60.70 20.92 80.54 C 13.95 80.46 6.97 80.52 0.00 80.50 L 0.00 17.49 C 3.50 17.51 6.99 17.50 10.49 17.49 C 10.52 11.66 10.49 5.83 10.50 0.00 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 94.50 0.00 L 157.50 0.00 C 157.51 6.98 157.47 13.95 157.54 20.93 C 136.52 21.06 115.49 21.02 94.47 20.95 C 94.52 13.97 94.49 6.98 94.50 0.00 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 178.50 0.00 L 241.50 0.00 C 241.54 6.95 241.41 13.91 241.59 20.86 C 220.56 21.16 199.51 20.96 178.48 20.96 C 178.52 13.97 178.49 6.99 178.50 0.00 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 262.50 0.00 L 287.00 0.00 C 287.00 16.00 286.99 32.00 287.00 48.00 C 304.00 48.01 321.00 48.00 338.00 48.00 L 338.00 119.00 C 321.00 119.00 304.00 118.99 287.00 119.01 C 286.89 127.21 287.21 135.41 286.84 143.61 C 279.91 143.38 272.97 143.54 266.03 143.52 C 265.94 123.67 266.05 103.82 265.97 83.98 C 265.94 81.27 267.36 78.76 267.04 76.02 C 266.71 69.70 267.76 63.26 266.02 57.09 C 265.97 45.08 266.02 33.07 266.00 21.07 C 264.81 21.01 263.62 20.94 262.44 20.85 C 262.57 13.90 262.47 6.95 262.50 0.00 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 0.00 101.50 C 6.99 101.50 13.98 101.51 20.97 101.49 C 21.07 120.12 20.92 138.76 21.05 157.39 C 19.87 157.45 18.69 157.51 17.51 157.57 C 17.50 161.04 17.49 164.52 17.50 168.00 L 0.00 168.00 L 0.00 101.50 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 38.48 147.03 C 59.49 146.97 80.50 146.99 101.51 147.02 C 101.49 154.01 101.50 161.01 101.50 168.00 L 38.50 168.00 C 38.50 161.01 38.51 154.02 38.48 147.03 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 122.45 147.10 C 143.47 146.91 164.50 146.99 185.53 147.05 C 185.47 154.04 185.51 161.02 185.50 168.00 L 122.50 168.00 C 122.48 161.03 122.55 154.06 122.45 147.10 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 206.48 147.04 C 227.49 146.97 248.50 146.98 269.52 147.03 C 269.48 154.02 269.51 161.01 269.50 168.00 L 206.50 168.00 C 206.49 161.01 206.52 154.03 206.48 147.04 Z" />
</g>
<svg id="1f6e43ff" x="37" y="37" width="214" height="95" >
  <rect id="level" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#1f6e43"/>
</svg>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the green box to a `<rect...` and update the `width` value. See similar [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alkhoo/JwkYm/12/) example. For other shapes (eg: slanted green bar), use `<polygon....` and change the `points=...` values.

Comment: Note: you can use `%` values on `width`, but usually I'd prefer to stick to `NNpx` instead.